# "if" Control Structures not functioning properly; error is messing with my whole program

Tags: if-statement, boolean, output

I have set up an if control structure to determine whether he number of command line arguments from my read prompt is only 3

However, when entered correctly initially, the program repeats the prompt, and after the second error, just exits he program.

Another issue is the output of the program, which also will not perform:

```
echo "Provide Three Names: "

read -r names

if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "Please enter three names. Try again: "
        read -r names


else

        # The script must determine the lexicographical order of the names

        $(sort) "$names"

        echo "Names in order are: "

        echo "${names[0]}"

        echo "${names[1]}"

        echo "${names[2]}"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the number of arguments, instead number of elements read.
May be the code bellow does what you want.

```
# print a prompt and read the values into an array
read -p "Provide three names: " -a names
while [ "${#names[@]}" -ne 3 ]
do
    echo "Please enter three names. Try again: "
    read -p "Provide three names: " -a names
done
# sort the array
IFS=$'\n'
names=($(sort <<<"${names[*]}"))
unset IFS
# print the result (array sorted)
echo "Names in order are: "
echo "${names[0]}"
echo "${names[1]}"
echo "${names[2]}"
```